# $mdDialog not instantiating controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am working with angular-material and I cannot get it to respect the controller option at all. Something as simple as:

```
this.mdDialog.show({
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        contentElement: '#signinDialog',
        controller: function($mdDialog) {
            console.log('notworking');
        },
    })
```

The function is never called when the dialog is opened. I have tried named functions and ES6 classes as well to the same result. No errors are present in the console, the dialog pops up but otherwise the dialog's controller isn't being used at all.

Edit:

Seems it is related to the use of `contentElement`. When using `templateUrl` instead it works fine. I am fine using that but the question remains why wouldn't it work when using `contentElement`? Is there something in the documentation I am missing that prevents a pre-rendered dialog from actually using a controller or is it a bug with angularjs-material?

Comment: Seems okay - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/QEAmKm?editors=1010#0

Comment: Updated with edit.

Comment: contentElement seems to work in codepen as well, but not locally. I'll chalk it up to a likely bug in the version of angular i am using.

Comment: Yes, contentElement works. Click on the Settings button in CodePen and see what files are loaded. I've seen many problems caused by out of date files.